# Get specific parts of a file path in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, path

I have a path string like

```
'/path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat/d=12520/file1.dat'
```

Q1: How can I get only `accescontrol.dat` from the path.

Q2: How can I get only `/path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat` from the path.

Comment: What's the rule that specifies `accescontrol.dat`? The 4th component from the left? 3rd from the right? The first one without an `=` character? The first one with a misspelled word in it?

Comment: The format is always like this? I mean with path/*.dat/d=something?

Comment: Anyway, look at `os.path.split()` or `os.path.dirname()`, and you can call that in a loop until you get what you want. If you get stuck, post what you were able to write and explain the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

url = '/path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat/d=12520/file1.dat'
match = re.search('^(.+/([^/]+\.dat))[^$]', url)

print match.group(1)
# Outputs /path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat
print match.group(2)
# Outputs accescontrol.dat
```

I edited this to work in python2 and to answer both questions (the earlier regex answer above only answers the first of the two)

Comment: You realize this is almost exactly the same to user590028's answer?

Comment: This might be making too many assumptions about the path, but you can get both with:

match = re.search('^(.+/([^/]+\.dat))[^$]', url)
Q1 is match.group(1)
Q2 is match.group(2)

Comment: Nope, it's completely different. He answered Q1 and I answered Q2. But my comment above answers both.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions

```
import re
ma = re.search('/([^/]+\.dat)/d=', path)
print ma.group(1)
```

Comment: This only answers the first question. See mine below (which originally answered only the second until I edited it)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `.split()`:

Q1:

```
str = '/path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat/d=12520/file1.dat'
[x for x in str.split('/') if x[-4:] == '.dat']
```

gives:

```
['accescontrol.dat','file1.dat']
```

A similar trick will answer Q2.

For more advanced file path manipulation I would recommend reading about `os.path`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating each level of folder/file into strings in a list.

```
path = '/path/eds/vs/accescontrol.dat/d=12520/file1.dat'.split("/")
```

This makes `path = ['path', 'eds', 'vs', 'accescontrol.dat', 'd=12520', 'file1.dat']`

Then from there, you can access each of the different parts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way

```
from pathlib import Path
h=r'C:\Users\dj\Pictures\Saved Pictures'
path = Path(h)
print(path.parts)
```

---

```
Path: .
('C:\\', 'Users', 'dj', 'Pictures', 'Saved Pictures')
```